# UWP Changing gridview element size programmatically

Tags: xaml, gridview, binding, uwp

I'm trying to use XAML binding to affect the gridview datatemplate element size from a slider on my screen.

I have a gridview made of thumbnails images where the elements are defined as following:

```
         <GridView.ItemTemplate  >
            <DataTemplate  >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            KeyDown="IsitenterThumb" 
                            BorderBrush="LightSeaGreen" 
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            PointerWheelChanged="ctlThumbnails_PointerWheelChanged">
                    <Image Source="{Binding thumb}" 
                           x:Name="thumbimg"
                           Visibility="Visible"
                           Height="{Binding ItemSize}" Width="{Binding ItemSize, ElementName=page}" Stretch="Uniform" 
                           Tapped="ThumbnailSelected" 
                           DoubleTapped="CloseThumbnails"
                           />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Margin="5,5" 
                               Foreground="White" 
                               Width="{Binding ItemSize}" 
                               />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
```

And I have the following variable defined as follow:

```
       public double ItemSize
       {
        get => _itemSize;
        set
        {
            if (_itemSize != value)
            {
                _itemSize = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ItemSize)));
            }
         }
       }

      private double _itemSize;

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

I would have thought that changing the value of ItemSize would have affected the gridview datatemplate. This is taken litterally from the PhotoLab sample.

Instead I get a single huge "thumbimg" per page... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's that `ElementName = page` ? you tried to bind it to a `Page`?

Comment: It's the MainPage

Comment: So, why've you put that `lementName = page` in your xaml? I don't think you are trying to set the Width of the image same as the width of `MainPage`. maybe that's why you are getting that huge sized Image.

Comment: You want an honnest answer?.... I tried so many strategies to do this, including searching the UI tree... I tried this adding this "ElementName" to the Binding out of despair, as that's the way it's done in the Photolab sample https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-photo-lab

Comment: ok, let's see if I can help, how many items is that `GridView` supposed to have?

Comment: The data template only has two items (the image and its filename). The GridView itself may have many hundreds on items but I load them a page and a half at the time (about 40). Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182876/discussion-between-muzib-and-francois-gagnon).

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I got it finally. I'm not quite sure what I was doing wrong above, but the code below works.

I have put the DataTemplate as part of a Page.Resource, I'm not sure if this is what was causing the binding issue. However the Xaml code looks like this:

```
      <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ThumbnailsTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            KeyDown="IsitenterThumb" 
                            BorderBrush="LightSeaGreen" 
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            <Image Source="{Binding thumb}" 
                            x:Name="thumbimg"
                            Visibility="Visible"
                            Height="{Binding ItemSize, ElementName=page}" Width="{Binding ItemSize, ElementName=page}" 
                           Stretch="Uniform" 
                           Tapped="ThumbnailSelected" 
                           DoubleTapped="CloseThumbnails"
                           />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Margin="5,5" 
                               Foreground="White" Width="{Binding ItemSize}" 
                               />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
     </Page.Resources>


     <GridView x:Name = "ctlThumbnails" Grid.Column="0" 
              BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" 
              Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height ="auto" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              Margin="30,30,30,30" KeyDown="IsitenterThumb"
              DoubleTapped="CloseThumbnails"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ThumbnailsTemplate}">
     </GridView>
```

And here is the C# code to affect the bound variable ItemSize

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

```
    public double ItemSize
    {
        get => _itemSize;
        set
        {
            if (_itemSize != value)
            {
                _itemSize = value;
                topcmdbarcontent.Text = "Thumb Size:" + _itemSize.ToString();
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ItemSize)));
            }
        }
    }
    private double _itemSize;
```

From this, when you change the value of ItemSize, through a ValueChanged event, for example, it does change the grid element size dynamically.